# how to extract valuefrom object and put it into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, angular8, immutability

i would like to extract filterPillvalue and put it into an array , and output of the array should be like this:

```js
mode = ['anyValue','Repsonding','Unresponsive']
```

Here is my attempt

```js
this.items = [
  {
    filterPillValue: 'anyValue',
    id: 'all-systems',
    label: 'All systems'
  },
  {
    filterPillValue: 'Responding',
    id: 'responding',
    label: 'Responding systems'
  },
  {
    filterPillValue: 'Unresponsive',
    id: 'unresponsive',
    label: 'Unresponsive systems'
  }
];
```

my attempt which does not work in this case

```js
mode = this.items.filter(x=>x.filterPillValue);
```

Comment: `map` is what you need `mode = this.items.map(x=>x.filterPillValue);`

Comment: works now. do we use map because it is an object instead of array?

Comment: @user21 no, you use `map` because you want to transform one array to another. See [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
items = [
  {
    filterPillValue: 'anyValue',
    id: 'all-systems',
    label: 'All systems'
  },
  {
    filterPillValue: 'Responding',
    id: 'responding',
    label: 'Responding systems'
  },
  {
    filterPillValue: 'Unresponsive',
    id: 'unresponsive',
    label: 'Unresponsive systems'
  }
];

const node=items.map(item=>item.filterPillValue)
console.log(node)
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work.

```
mode = this.items.map(({filterPillValue}) => filterPillValue);
```

or

```
mode = this.items.map((item) => item.filterPillValue);
```